# Pygame: Making things move slower than 1

Tags: python, pygame

I made a little Space Invaders like game, everything is good except that I feel like my enemies I programmed move too fast. If I make their movement speed under 1 such as 0.5, they won't even move. Is there a way I can make the movement even slower?

Here is the code for my enemy unit:

```
import math


WINDOW = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 900))


class Enemy (pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        super(). __init__ ()
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((20,20))
        self.image.fill((255,0,0))
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image,(COLOUR4), (10,10),10)
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center=(0,0)
        self.dx=2
        self.dy=1

    def update(self):
        self.rect.centery += self.dy


for i in range (100):
    enemy = Enemy()
    enemy.rect.x=random.randrange(750)
    enemy.rect.y=random.randrange(100)
    enemy_list.add(enemy)
    all_sprites_list.add(enemy)
```

Comment: Your indentation is wrong, please can you fix it so that it's clear what your code is doing? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `pygame.Rect`s can only have ints as their coordinates and floats get truncated. If you want floating point values as the velocities, you have to store the actual position as a separate attribute (or two as in the first example below), add the velocity to it every frame and then assign the new position to the rect.

```
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos):  # You can pass the position as a tuple, list or vector.
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((20, 20))
        self.image.fill((255, 0, 0))
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, (COLOUR4), (10, 10), 10)
        # The actual position of the sprite.
        self.pos_x = pos[0]
        self.pos_y = pos[1]
        # The rect serves as the blit position and for collision detection.
        # You can pass the center position as an argument.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(self.pos_x, self.pos_y))
        self.dx = 2
        self.dy = 1

    def update(self):
        self.pos_x += self.dx
        self.pos_y += self.dy
        self.rect.center = (self.pos_x, self.pos_y)
```

I recommend using [vectors](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2), since they are more versatile and concise.

```
from pygame.math import Vector2

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos):
        # ...
        self.pos = Vector2(pos)
        self.velocity = Vector2(2, 1)

    def update(self):
        self.pos += self.velocity
        self.rect.center = self.pos
```

Comment: I've never really used Vectors. Do I have to make Vector 2 a variable?

Comment: `Vector2` is a class which you can import from the `pygame.math` module. You can also write `pygame.math.Vector2(2, 1)` to create a new vector instance. If you don't know how classes work, I recommend reading the chapters 12 and 13 of [Program Arcade Games](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=introduction_to_classes&lang=en#section_12). If you want to learn more about vectors in general, you could check out [khanacademy.org](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra).